# Add Secundary IP on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to use more than one IP on my Google Compute Engine, for use my SSL Certificate. What I need to do to add a Secundary IP on my instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You an configure an [static network address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress), this link will guide you on how to do this.

Comment: Trying here! Update soon

Comment: To create your instance in the Developers Console, you need to click on 'Show advanced options' to be able to set the flag '--can-ip-forward'.   For the route, you can also click on 'Networks' > select the network for you instance > in the 'Routes' section > click on 'Create new

Comment: When creating the route, you will select the required options.  Once your instance is created, you can SSH to add the new virtual interface to your instance, as the instructions provided in the link

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you're trying to assign an additional external (Internet) IP to your instance.

Protocol Forwarding (Forwarding rules) are exactly designed for this. Here is relevant documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/#targetinstances